# how to handle large number of If condition in C?

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a code which has large number of if contions like below:

```
if(condition1)
{
  //code
}
else
  //code

if(condition2)
{
  //code
}
else
  //code
..... 
.....
```

these if conditions are like 18-20 and I think using if conditions will make code complex. How can I write my code to avoid so much ifconitions?

Comment: How complex are the conditions? Are the different conditions related? Could you change some to use e.g. `switch` instead? Maybe you should start thinking about a different design that doesn't need so many `if` in the implementation?

Comment: What does your code do? Whether there is a simple solution or not will depend on the conditions themselves and on how data is organised.

Comment: You don't provide us with enough information to answer your question. Try to give more details so we can give you a specific answer.

Comment: If you find that the function with all the conditions is getting too complex due to its size, try dividing it into smaller functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very simple condition and just many of them, you can use the switch function. An example of how to use it would be

```
int choice;
choice = 32; // logic to fill choice with whatever your variable in condition is

switch(choice)
{
case 1:
// some logic
break;
case 2:
// some logic
break;
case 32: 
// some logic
break;
}
```

And so forth. You get the gist.

If your conditions are more complex, you will have to use if statements instead. Consider if else logic. Like this:

```
if (condition1) 
{
//logic
}
else if (condition2)
{
//logic
}
else
{
//logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider Ternary operator

```
(expr) ? <true logic> : <false logic>
```